# TCL Expect: how to remove a trailing newline

Tags: tcl

I am executing this expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#####config file content :: user1|server1

set lx [exec awk {-F|} {/server1/ {print $1}} config]

puts "Values is $lx of server1."
```

The output is:

```
Values is user1
of server1.
```

There is a trailing new line in `$lx` that i am unable to remove.
I have tried :

```
set x [string trimright $lx \n]
set x [string trimright $lx "\n"]
set x [string trim $lx \n]
```

But there is always a `\n` left on the end of `$x`. How can this newline be removed?

Comment: Are you sure that's a `\n`? Could it be a vertical tab `\v` or a form feed `\f` instead which would explain why the things you tried didn't seem to work? In any case, simply using `string trim $lx` should do the trick.

Comment: Used :: regsub -all [\r\n] $lx "" lx to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

By default `string trim` will remove any whitespace-type characters from either end of the string, so you could just `set x [string trim $lx]`.

I would be inclined to do the whole processing in Expect like this:

```
set x [string trim [lindex [split [read [open config]] | ] 0]]
```

Comment: Used :: regsub -all [\r\n] $lx "" lx to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Used :: regsub -all [\r\n] $lx "" lx to fix this.

Comment: Note that regsub command will only delete the **first** `\r` **or** `\n` found in the string. If you want to remove only *trailing* \r **and** \n, use the regex `{[\r\n]+$}`, or `{\s+$}` to remove all trailing whitespace (in which case, just use `string trim`)

Comment: And you will need to quote that regex with braces or expect will see it as attempting to execute the **command** `\r\n`

Comment: @glennjackman There's the `-all` switch there so it won't just delete the first `\r` or `\n`, but I do agree it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way of fixing this is `string trimright $variable "\r\n"`, since Expect doesn't hide the details of CR/NL processing from you (unlike normal Tcl I/O operations). This is intentional, of course — Expect is often used in situations where being able to see the real details of terminal handling is useful — but means you have to deal with it.